# Can't ping to other networks

Tags: windows, networking

In our company we have 3 different local networks. I can ping to other local networks from my system, but can't ping to a particular network from another local machine which is coming under the same network in my system. Its firewall is OFF.

Comment: Are you pinging an IP or a name? Is the default gateway of the other machine set correctly? Is the routing table of the other machine correct?

Comment: Are you able to run tracert to see where the communication stops?

Comment: pinging with ip not itz name, all are setting correctly on that machine. I can ping same from my system.

Comment: Are the two machines in question connected to the same switch?  Are they in the same general physical area?   It almost sounds like the machine that you cannot ping from is on a VLAN or possibly the routes are messed up.   Have you tried running the command 'route print' on both machines and comparing the output between both machines?

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBt\Parameters
```

In the right pane of Registry Editor, delete the `NodeType` and `DhcpNodeType` values if they are present.

Comment: no NodeType and DhcpNodeType is present in regedit.

Comment: sometimes connection is fine but it disconnects without any notification